# Use pyproj new projection initialization method when setting a CRS in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

## Issue

Using [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/):

this:

```
(...)
t_srs = 4326
gdf.set_geometry('geom', crs={'init': u'epsg:'+str(t_srs)}, inplace=True)
```

or this:

```
(...)
gpd.read_postgis(sql_string, conn, geom_col='geom', crs={'init': u'epsg:'+str(t_srs)})
```

raise a warning today:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyproj/crs.py:77:     
FutureWarning: 
    '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated.     
    '<authority>:<code>'  is the preferred initialization method.
  return _prepare_from_string(" ".join(pjargs))
```

and if I remove the `'init'` key of the `crs` [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), I got this error;

`CRSError: Invalid CRS input: {'epsg:4326'}`

And if, by chance, I try with `{'epsg':'4326'}` or `{'epsg':4326}` ; these errors are respectively raised:

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: {"epsg": "4326"}: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: Missing "type" key)
```

and:

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: {"epsg": 4326}: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: Missing "type" key)
```

## Question

Is it already possible to write some [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) code that corresponds to the new* [pyproj](http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/) projection initialization method using  `<authority>:<code>` instead of  `+init=<authority>:<code>` ?

- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`'<authority>:<code>'` in the error means that you need just to use `crs='EPSG:4326'` instead of `crs={'epsg:4326'}`.

Comment: Passing just EPSG number is also possible `crs=4326`. In the example above it would be the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

As too often, I continue cobbling around with my code after having posted my question, and I figure it out:

## Short

**Do not** pass a dictionary but a **string** as a CRS!

## Explanation

I.e, in concrete terms, change the two previous pieces of code that thrown the `FutureWarning` into

this:

```
(...)
t_srs = 4326
gdf.set_geometry('geom', crs=(u'epsg:'+str(t_srs)), inplace=True)
```

or this:

```
(...)
gpd.read_postgis(sql_string, conn, geom_col='geom', crs=(u'epsg:'+str(t_srs)))
```

Notice the **parentheses** instead of the curly braces, which mean now that `crs` is a **string** and no more a dictionary.

Here is, as an example, the help of the `geopandas.read_postgis()` method where it is discreetly suggested:

```
help(gpd.read_postgis)
Help on function read_postgis in module geopandas.io.sql:

read_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='geom', crs=None, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, parse_dates=None, params=None)
    Returns a GeoDataFrame corresponding to the result of the query
    string, which must contain a geometry column in WKB representation.

    Parameters
    ----------
    sql : string
        SQL query to execute in selecting entries from database, or name
        of the table to read from the database.
    con : DB connection object or SQLAlchemy engine
        Active connection to the database to query.
    geom_col : string, default 'geom'
        column name to convert to shapely geometries
    crs : dict or str, optional
        CRS to use for the returned GeoDataFrame; if not set, tries to
        determine CRS from the SRID associated with the first geometry in
        the database, and assigns that to all geometries.

    See the documentation for pandas.read_sql for further explanation
    of the following parameters:
    index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params

    Returns
    -------
    GeoDataFrame

    Example
    -------
    PostGIS
sql = "SELECT geom, kind FROM polygons"
    SpatiaLite
sql = "SELECT ST_AsBinary(geom) AS geom, kind FROM polygons"
df = geopandas.read_postgis(sql, con)
```